# angular - node.js , HttpClient put connection succeeded but did not work successfully

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I tried to use angular `HttpClient` `get`, `delete`, `post` to connect to the node.js API, all are successful.

But when I connected with the `put` method, I found that I can connect, but there is no other reflection.

For example:

Angular `put` to connect `/api/edit/:id`

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

    constructor( private http: HttpClient,) { }

    editData(data: any, id: any){
      this.http.put<any>(this.Url + "/api/edit/" + id, data).subscribe(res =>{

      });
    }
```

Node.js `put` API `/api/edit/:id`:

```
router.put('/api/edit/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("edit api connected!");
  res.status(200).json();
});
```

The working node.js server `cmd` window show like this log:

`OPTIONS /api/edit/5c481dedbe234c2dec23c6a0 200 1.333 ms - 3`

But not show `"edit api connected!"`;
I don't know why the `OPTIONS` is displayed.
This can happen with other methods, like `DELETE`, but does not affect the operation.

I try to using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to connect same AIP, It's work, the log like this:

```
edit api connected!
PUT /api/edit/testid 200 0.635 ms - -
```

I have tried to change router : `/api/edit/` (without parameters), just can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send requests via chrome or other browsers (using angular httpclient) to a different domain (not the same origin) there will be two requests. The first is OPTION a pre flight request to check which methods (GET, PUT, POST etc.) are allowed on server side. An OPTION request expects a response with CORS header:

For Expample:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with, user-id
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1
Allow: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS
```

When this request fails the browser does not send the actual request `PUT` in your case. With Postman there is no OPTIONS pre flight, that is why it works.

To get your node.js server work with angular you have to use cors middleware e.g:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

More information here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: You answer is slightly misleading. Browser doesn't always send the OPTIONS request. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: oh...god, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, I missing `PUT` method. postman is no longer restricted?`Cors` middleware is great, thx.

Comment: @Praveen updated my answer. Browser use OPTIONS pre flight for cross domain request. Was it that what you meant?

Comment: Quote:  postman is no longer restricted?

Postman has no standard security like CORS implemented, It just sends your request